# CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is set correctly but seems to be ignored by asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, localization, internationalization

Im struggling with gettings the values from the correct strings.txt in my resource files in my \bin folder when switching languages.

I have a domain.com (for English) and a domain.nl (for Dutch). It however doesnt seem to matter which domain I use and how I set the currentUICulture, the language shown to the user is always the same!

[default.aspx.vb]

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Shared rm As ResourceManager = HttpContext.Current.Application("RM")

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Label.Text = rm.GetString("homewelcome")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        SetLanguage(Request.Url.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SetLanguage(ByVal URL As String)
        Dim lang As String = ""
        If URL.Contains("www.domain.nl") Then
            lang = "nl"
        ElseIf URL.Contains("www.domain.com") Then
            lang = "en"
        End If
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang)
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[global.asax]

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Application("RM") = New ResourceManager("strings", Assembly.Load("strings"))
End Sub
```

In my bin folder I have:

bin\strings.txt
bin\nl\strings.nl.txt
bin\en\strings.en.txt

I generate the dlls like so:

```
resgen strings.txt strings.resources
al /embed:strings.resources,strings.resources /out:strings.dll
resgen nl\strings.nl.resources
al /embed:nl\strings.nl.resources,strings.nl.resources /out:nl\strings.resources.dll /c:nl
resgen en\strings.en.resources
al /embed:en\strings.en.resources,strings.en.resources /out:en\strings.resources.dll /c:en
```

Now, all files seem to be created correctly.

However, when I go to the www.domain.com, the values from bin\strings.txt are used and NOT (like I would expect and desire), the values from bin\en\strings.en.txt

Im running on Windows 7 with IIS7.5
When I debugged I found that in my InitializeCulture method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    SetLanguage(Request.Url.ToString)
End Sub
```

when I check for the current `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString` its equal to "en", so it seems that the culture is SET correctly, its only that not the correct strings.dll is used.

But there's a more strange things going on: I have this in my default.aspx `<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:lookingfor%>" />`

1. When I aproach www.domain.nl (the Dutch domain!), the Literal1 controls displays the value from "App_LocalResources\default.aspx.en.resx" and the rm.getstring shows me a value from bin\strings.txt
   And when I check the current System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString its equal to "nl"
2. When I aproach www.domain.com (the English domain!), the Literal1 controls displays the value from "App_LocalResources\default.aspx.en.resx" and the rm.getstring shows me a value from bin\strings.txt
   And when I check the current `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString` its equal to "en"

What is going on here?

So when using www.domain.nl, the WRONG strings.dll is used, but the CORRECT .resx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ResourceManager's `GetString(string, CultureInfo)` overload to get strings in correct language.

BTW. global.asax is probably the better place to set CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture.

**EDIT** Providing code sample per Peter's request

### Globabal.asax

For starters, I would detect and store culture:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request '
    Dim culture As CultureInfo
    Dim uri As Uri = Request.Url
    If uri.ToString().Contains("nederlands") Then
        culture = New CultureInfo("nl-NL")
    ElseIf uri.ToString().Contains("polski") Then
        culture = New CultureInfo("pl-PL")
    Else
        culture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
    End If

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture
End Sub
```

Depending on what you want to do, it might not be the best Function to overload, in your case I believe `Session_Start` is better (that is unless you want to give users an ability to switch language).
Another thing is, I didn't test it with domain names, I used query parameters and haven't validate them properly but it was just for the purpose of example only.

### Create App_LocalResources

Instead of instantiating ResourceManager and compiling your resources manually, I can only suggest you to use App_LocalResources. You just need to right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, choose Add -> Add Asp.Net Folder -> App_LocalResources.

### Create resource files

Create appropriately named resource files: Default.aspx.resx, Default.aspx.nl.resx and add the contents you want to localize to them. In my case it was:

Default.aspx.resx (neutral aka fall-back culture resource file)

```
label1  Some label
label2  Some other label
```

Default.aspx.nl.resx (Sorry for my poor Dutch)

```
label1  Dit is een etiket
label2  Dit is ander etiket
```

Default.aspx.pl.resx

```
label1  Jakaś tam labelka
label2  Jakaś inna labelka
```

### Default.aspx.vb (code behind)

In code behind you can programmatically modify contents of your web page like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Label2.Text = Me.GetLocalResourceObject("label2")
End Sub
```

For many reasons I would not recommend this method (especially it should not be used in page load handler), however it is sometimes needed.

### Default.aspx

Finally we are at our beautiful (and very useful) web page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:label1 %>"></asp:Label>
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, you can access the resources with following expression: `<%$ Resources:label1 %>`. This will give you the string associated with label1 resource key. Important thing to note: runat="server" is not optional.

HTH. You may want to read [the tutorial on Asp.Net Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx) as well.

Comment: Could you provide me with a code sample of how you would do that? Because I've been struggling with this for at least 2 weeks now. Tried placing it in 
Sub Session_OnStart(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
But no good. Also actually, I dont want to pass the culture every time I call the Getstring method...:)

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick! And ps: i didnt notice you already answered here...sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use Culture & UICulture Page properties:

VB:

```
    UICulture = "en-US"
    Culture = "en-US"

    Dim cultureInfo As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")

    Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo
    Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo
```

C#:

```
        UICulture = "en-US";
        Culture = "en-US";    
        Globalization.CultureInfo  cultureInfo =  Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;


Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
Dim ui As String = String.Empty

If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString("UI")) Then
    'ui = "en-US"
    If Not Session("UI") Is Nothing Then
        ui = Session("UI")
    Else
        ui = "en-US"
    End If
Else
    ui = Request.QueryString("UI")
End If

UICulture = ui
Culture = ui

Dim cultureInfo As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ui)

Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo

MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
```

I'm passing UI value through Session and QueryString, if the UI doesn't have value I set it to "en-US"

Comment: You mention: UICulture = "en-US"
Would that read values from default.aspx.en.resx?
Also, WHERE would you add those lines of code?
Sorry for all my questions, but I've been struggling with this for at least 2 weeks without success...:(