# resourcemanager uses wrong UICulture to serve content! Always returns neutral culture

Tags: asp.net, localization, currentculture, currentuiculture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is set correctly but seems to be ignored by asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816773/currentthread-currentuiculture-is-set-correctly-but-seems-to-be-ignored-by-asp-ne)

I've asked on many forums, but no one seems to be able to help me!

default.aspx:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="<%$Resources:lookingfor %>" runat="server"/>
```

default.aspx.vb:

```
Shared rm As ResourceManager = HttpContext.Current.Application("RM")

  Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        Dim cultureInfo As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en")
        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo
        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo

        'Here I log the value of currentculture
        ReportError("default.aspx:InitializeCulture.CurrentCulture", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString)
        ReportError("default.aspx:InitializeCulture.CurrentUICulture", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString)

        'log file shows that:
        'CurrentCulture =   "en-US"
        'CurrentUICulture=  "en-US"
    End Sub

   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            'again logging the currentculture:
            ReportError("default.aspx:page_load.CurrentCulture", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString)
            ReportError("default.aspx:page_load.CurrentUICulture", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString)

            'log file shows that:
            'CurrentCulture =   "en-US"
            'CurrentUICulture=  "en-US"

            Me.Page.Title = rm.GetString("homewelcome") 
        End If
    End Sub
```

global.asax:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Application("RM") = New ResourceManager("strings", Assembly.Load("strings"))
End Sub
```

\bin folder:
In my bin folder I have:

```
bin\strings.txt
bin\nl\strings.nl.txt
bin\en\strings.en.txt
```

I generate the dlls like so:

```
resgen strings.txt strings.resources
al /embed:strings.resources,strings.resources /out:strings.dll
resgen nl\strings.nl.resources
al /embed:nl\strings.nl.resources,strings.nl.resources /out:nl\strings.resources.dll /c:nl
resgen en\strings.en.resources
al /embed:en\strings.en.resources,strings.en.resources /out:en\strings.resources.dll /c:en
```

Now when I load default.aspx

The Literal1 control shows: 'What are you looking for?' 
this is the value from App_LocalResources\default.aspx.en.resx, so that is correct.

But the Page Title (Me.Page.Title = rm.GetString("homewelcome")) shows the value from bin\strings.txt!
That is ofcourse incorrect as I would want it to show the value from bin\en\strings.txt

So the resource manager is ignoring the culture, whereas the Literal is using the CORRECT culture!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Any particular reason why you cannot use the solution I gave you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816773/currentthread-currentuiculture-is-set-correctly-but-seems-to-be-ignored-by-asp-ne/5818814#5818814)? Are you using .Net 1.x? Your tags should reflect that as well as programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the strings files all in the same folder. I don't know what are your setup but by default I think the ResourceManager try to look for resource in the same folder and if it doesn't find a appropriate one fall back to the default one which in your case is strings.txt.

[image]

Comment: the .resx files work correctly (if you read my post you see that the literal is assigned the correct value). Its the resource dll's that are causing the problem when I try to read them with rm.getstring