# ASP.NET Resource Manager RaceCondition in Multilingual Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, race-condition

We're using resource manager to load resources based on Thread UI culture in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application.We set thread culture as below:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var lang = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"];
    var ci = new CultureInfo(lang);
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
    culture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "AM";
    culture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "PM";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
}
```

We think there is a RaceCondition problem in resource manager that cause loading resources with invalid UI Culture for current thread,For example  we see that CurrentUICulture  and CurrentCulture is en-US but loaded resources are in it-IT.This happen often when application is under load.We did a research about this and find these threads:

[ASP.Net MVC resource files are sometimes incorrectly loaded by the ResouceManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652351/asp-net-mvc-resource-files-are-sometimes-incorrectly-loaded-by-the-resoucemanage)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/806505/race-condition-in-system-resources-resourcemanager-leads-to-incorrect-resources-being-loaded

we did every thing mentioned in the two above links but nothing change,We are now so tired.Special thanks to Any one can help around this?

Comment: Did you try to move this piece of code in `Application_BeginRequest`?

Comment: Yes,But nothing changed

Comment: i am having the same issue , did you solve it ? if you did please share the solution, thank you